# Calculation error while using ceil function in C++

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, ceil

I m new to C++. I m trying to implement a segmented sieve to find prime numbers, between given numbers m and n. My logic might be also wrong. Below is the code i have written,

```
long long m;
long long n;
std::cin >> m;
std::cin >> n;
vector<bool> sieve(n-m+1,true);
for(int i=2;i<sqrt(n);i++) {
    long long j = ceil(float(m)/float(i));
    while(j*i <= n) {
        sieve[j*i - m] = false;
        j++;
    }
}
```

The code works for small value of m (i.e. the starting number). However, when i m increasing the value of m to order 10^8. I get a seg fault because the value of (j*i-m) goes negative. During debugging for a value of m = 63458900, for i = 3, i'm getting j = 21152966, when it's supposed to be 21152967 after the ceil function.

The value of n-m is always less than 10^6.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Cast to double, not to float.

Comment: 63458900/3 is indeed 21152966

Comment: @RADAR, sorry my bad in calculation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you get is off by one - it should be `21152967` after `ceil`.

You can simplify

```
ceil(float(m)/float(i))
```

to

```
(m + i - 1) / i
```

and thereby avoid potential imprecisions. 
Substituting the corresponding values yields `(63458900ll + 3 - 1)/3` which should be `21152967` on your machine.